# Users from my ISP's IP range can't hear my radio stream but others can

Tags: ip, tcpip, streaming

I'm streaming a radio via Shoutcast server from a PC in my office and ppl from around the world can hear it in browser or via wmedialayer/winamp, but people from my ISP (including me when I use outer IP) can't, a stream simply can't be opened in browser or winamp/wmediaplayer. What should I do?

Comment: When I go to http://192.168.1.100:8000 in my browser I can hear the radio stream, but when I use my outer IP:port then it doesn't work.

Comment: You should consult your work's IT department.  They will be able to assist in streaming music from your desk. :)

Comment: Search for [hairpin NAT](http://serverfault.com/search?q=hairpin+nat).  Basically if you are using NAT, then people inside your NAT must use your internal address, unless you do some special configuration on the NAT device.

Comment: @Zoredache: Ppl inside my NAT couldn't use my local IP addres, it's address from my router...

Comment: Yes, I understand that, and if you would follow that search you would see lots of other people with the same 'problem', and several solutions to it depending on your setup.

Answer (score 2):

Some ISPs do not allow routing between IPs on the same network. We had a similar issue with a small rural school where most of the town couldn't access the sit hosted at the school because they were on the same subnet.

The simplest solution is to rent a Shoutcast server from a third party and stream to that. You can find them very cheap.